# Saving state of a dynamically added view through an adapter

Tags: android

I've been struggling with this problem for two days and haven't found anything helpful online.
My setup is like this, I've a Gridview which I am populating with images through API. Now each cell of GridView contains a button , when clicked is supposed to add an overlay to the cell. This is being done dynamically depending on the values through webservice. Now the problem is when I scroll up or down the overlay that was added shifts to other cells.How can I tackle this  problem?

What I've tried:

I've tried the SparseBooleanArray solution which is used to save the state of the checkboxes through saving the position,but this approach will not solve the problem as I am struggling with keeping the state of the view intact.

What I suspect:

The code adds the overlay through a method which is called on click of the button. I am using the clicked position to get the cell through gridView.getChildat(position) and adding the overlay as a child to it. I think my convertView is not updating that's why the overlay keeps on drawing on different cell positions.

Relevant code:

This is inside my getView method,

```
 if (convertView == null) {
       convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_image_row, null);
       holder = new Holder();
       holder.iv_product_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_iv_product_image) ;
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams iv_product_image_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(imageWidth,imageHeight) ;
       holder.iv_product_image.setLayoutParams(iv_product_image_params) ;
       iv_product_image_params = null ;
       holder.iv_loader_image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_iv_loader_image) ;
       holder.bt_expand_save_overlay = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_bt_expand_save_overlay) ;
       holder.tv_productname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_productname) ;
       customFonts.SetSoureLightFont(holder.tv_productname) ;
       holder.tv_sellingprice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_sellingprice) ;
       customFonts.SetSoureLightFont(holder.tv_sellingprice) ;
       holder.tv_price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_tv_price) ;
       customFonts.SetSoureRegularFont(holder.tv_price) ;
       holder.parent_cell = null;
       convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
       holder = (Holder) convertView.getTag();
}
```

EDIT : This is how I am setting tags with the positions...

```
                 if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
                     holder.bt_expand_save_overlay.setTag("1,"+position) ;
                     int i=0;
                    for (i=0; i<savedItemsHashMap.size(); i++) {
                    HashMap<String,String> savedItems = new HashMap<String, String>() ;
                savedItems = savedItemsHashMap.get(i) ;
if (savedItems.get(GlobalVariables.KEY_PRODUCT_ID).equals(mapStr.get(GlobalVariables.KEY_ID))) {
                                holder.bt_expand_save_overlay.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.wishlist_saved_drawable) ;
                                break ;
                            }
                        } 

                        if (i==savedItemsHashMap.size()) {
                            holder.bt_expand_save_overlay.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.wishlist_unsaved_drawable) ;     
                        }
                    } else {
                     holder.bt_expand_save_overlay.setTag("0,"+position) ;
                    }
```

This is how I am binding click listener inside getView,I am saving the position in the tags.

```
holder.bt_expand_save_overlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String getTagString = (String)v.getTag() ;
    String [] items = getTagString.split(",");
    selectedExpandButton = Integer.valueOf(items[1]) ;
    ExpandSaveForLaterOverlay (selectedExpandButton) ;
}
```

The ExpandSaveForLaterOverlay adds the view to the selected cell but this does not remain on the same child when scrolled.

Thanks in advance for any help or tips!

Update: I checked the google play music application and they have the same setup. They have a gridview with a button which shows a menu overlay on click. But before scrolling the menu goes invisible, and only after that it scrolls. Is there no way to save the overlay in the view instance itself?

Comment: Are you adding same overlay to all items ?

Comment: The class ExpandSaveForLaterOverlay adds two or three types of layouts depending upon the id's of the item.Nonetheless if the layout is same then also same problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally my idea about android architecture was wrong. What I needed was to show the added layout as dropdown. And the added layout should be scrolled when the gridview is scrolled.Which is not possible in any way by available android sdk. I might have to make my own view for such implementations which will keep track of the virtual y and x position of the added overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setTag() on imageview in adapter like

```
holder.imageView.setTag(position);
```

And getTag() when you are  adding the overlay as a child like

```
holder.imageView.getTag();
```

then add overlay.

Comment: Hi keshav thanks for the answer, but I believe I am doing the same, If you take a look at my click listener that I am binding with the view in getView, I am getting the position through tag only. The problem arises when I scroll my gridView, the added overlay is visible on different cells, not the cell that I ADDED it to initially.

Comment: I am not talking about settag() for convertview but for imageview to which you are adding overlay in your code you are setting tag for whole view,this is different.

Comment: I had somehow removed the code but now you can check the question again, I've updated it. I am setting position as tag to the bt_expand_save_overlay which I am extracting it in my ExpandSaveForLaterOverlay function. Thus I am getting the view through position only and then adding it to the view as a child. This approach works properly only till the moment I scroll. After scrolling the gridview the expanded overlay showsup at random positions.